# What types are read from byte array?

Tags: java

I try to understand what data types are read from a byte array. These methods seem to follow a common pattern:

```
public class Reader {

    static short readA(byte[] bytes, int i) {
        int s = ((((short) bytes[i]) & 255) << 8)
                | (((short) bytes[i + 1]) & 255);
        return (short) s;
    }

    static int readB(byte[] bytes, int i) {
        return ((bytes[i] & 255) << 8)
                | (bytes[i + 1] & 255);
    }

    static int readC(byte[] bytes, int i) {
        return ((bytes[i] & 255) << 24)
                | ((bytes[i + 1] & 255) << 16)
                | ((bytes[i + 2] & 255) << 8)
                | (bytes[i + 3] & 255);
    }

}
```

Does `readC` read a signed integer? Does `readB` read a signed short? What does `readA` read?

Comment: I think that your question isn't related to reverse engineering. Nonetheless, `readA` returns `short` created as concatenation of `bytes[i]` and `bytes[i+1]` (i.e. if `bytes[i]=00000010` and `bytes[i+1]=10000011`, it will return `10100000011`). `readB` returns the same except that will be of type `int`, while `readC` returns an `int` representing concatenation of `bytes[i]`, `bytes[i+1]`, `bytes[i+2]` and `bytes[i+3]`.

Comment: assume i = 0   bytes = [1,2,3,4]   so bytes[0] is the first byte in array  it is left shifted by 8 so 1 << 8 == 256 | 2   ==  258 the & 255  is there to take only the byte from input ie instead of [1,2,3,4]  the input can be [0x8097abef,....]  the & 255 will strip the 8097ab an will take only ef for left shifting  ie ef << 8 ie the result will be 0xef00 | yy

Comment: @bart1e  please put answers in the answer box, not in comments. Thanks

Comment: @blabb as well.

Comment: @bart1e Yeah, well I probably should have asked this question on Stackoverflow. Thanks for responding anyway. Does the conversion of `(short) bytes[i]` have any effect? `&` is calculated using `int` nonetheless, isn't it? The code of my question is decompiled java code. The decompiled smali code of `readA` uses `int-to-short v0, v0` followed by `and-int/lit16 v0, v0, 0xff`. I guess that cast could have been left out.

Comment: You are right. If you remove this cast, the result (as well as resulting bytecode) will not change. @IgorSkochinsky I didn't write an answer since this question doesn't seem to be about reverse engineering (and my comment just wasn't composite enough to be posted as an answer). As maiermic said, it is more suitable for stackoverflow.

Comment: understanding code is also reverse engineering, this question is not necessarily offtopic here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets Break the algo into pieces before trying to understand

the algo is broken into pieces using **bodmas** (bracket open ,divide ,multiply ,add, subtract )

and/or [**Operator precedence**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

lets take the uncasted readB first

```
static int readB(byte[] bytes, int i) {
    return ((bytes[i] & 255) << 8)
            | (bytes[i + 1] & 255);
}
```

prototype of function says it takes an array of bytes and an integer does some thing and returns an int back

```
static int readB(byte[] bytes, int i)
```

body of the function (where it does the aforementioned something

```
return ((bytes[i] & 255) << 8) | (bytes[i + 1] & 255);
```

there are two bracketed expression one of which has a child

```
1. ((bytes[i] & 255) << 8)    
          I. (bytes[i] & 255)
 3. (bytes[i + 1] & 255)
```

breaking the child expression apart it has three components  a constant 255 and two variables
which are arguments or inputs provided to the function
the byte array bytes[] and
the integer i
since i is an int the array can range from 0 to 2^31 -1

( think what will happen if you provide a null array or
 an array with just 1 value or 
an array with 2^31-1 values
or int >= array size
([bounds checking](https://rextester.com/live/ETUY42530)
this link has the following code check the results and see the thrown exception

```
{  
    static byte foo[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 };
    static int readB(byte[] bytes, int i)
    {
        return ((bytes[i] & 255) << 8) | (bytes[i + 1] & 255);
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < foo.length ; i++ ) 
        {
            System.out.printf("bounds check %d %d %d\n" , i , foo[i] , readB(foo,i));
        }
    }
}
```

result of running the code

```
Compilation time: 1.05 sec, absolute running time: 0.22 sec,  
cpu time: 0.15 sec, memory peak: 18 Mb, absolute service time: 1,27 sec

Error(s), warning(s):

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
    at Rextester.readB(source.java:12)
    at Rextester.main(source.java:18)

bounds check 0 1 258
bounds check 1 2 515
bounds check 2 3 772
bounds check 3 4 1029
bounds check 4 5 1286
bounds check 5 6 1543
bounds check 6 7 1800
```

)

```
bytes[i] & 255
```

this actually is superfluous operation

the bytes[i] array is already of BYTE type so the values can never exceed 255 and there is no point stripping the rest 
this would only make sense if the type is > BYTE like **WORD foo[]** which can hold anything from **0x0000 to 0xffff** or **int foo[]** which can hold anything from **0x00000000 to 0xffffffff** so stripping the hibyte and highwords may make sense .

in this specific code we can safely ignore this

so basically  it takes two bytes from the given position  and folds them into a bigger type
so readA returns a SHORT and readB returns and INT type

ie readA takes two bytes from a give position and folds it into anything between 
0x0000 and 0xffff
readB takes two bytes from a given position and folds into anything between 
0x00000000 and 0xffffffff (actually  it is same as  0x00000 and 0xffff if not for size of type calculation or pointer arithmetic's )

the third readC now should be clear enough for you  ittakes 4 bytes and folds it into anything between 0x00000000 and 0xffffffff (this function utilizes the whole range not unlike the readA() / readB()

see the shifts **24,16,8**  which puts
**byte[ position 1]** at **0xAA-??????**
**byte[ position 2]** at **0xAA-BB-????**
**byte [position 3]** at **0xAA-BB-CC-??** and
**byte [position 4]** at **0xAA-BB-CC-DD**
and returns back **0xAABBCCDD**